# Make GWT Vertical Panel stay centred on zoom out

Tags: java, gwt

I've added the following code to my `VerticalPanel` which all other widgets are attached to. It behaves as expected, and everything is centred and in line with the HTML title defined in my `application.html` file (to give you a reference).

```
this.vPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

However, when I zoom out below ~ 120% on Chrome, Firefox, and IE my HTML title stays perfectly centred, but my Vertical Panel moves to the left, as pictured below (I have to cover proprietary information):

[image]

How would I make it in line with the HTML title on any zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the GWT example project demonstrated the behavior I need, and so used its method of making an HTML `table` in the `application.html` file

```
<table align="center">
```

I then added a row

```
      <tr>
        <td id="vPanelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
```

And then from my `onModuleLoad` method I called `RootPanel.get("vPanelContainer").add(GUI)` which contains the `VerticalPanel`

As you can see, I am an absolute beginner in HTML, but thought I'd answer the question anyway.